# corona lua - how to test if a point is 'inside' a displayObject's physics shape?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

corona lua - how to test if a point is 'inside' a displayObject's physics shape?

This is the 'shape' that would be used when performing the "addBody" physics function to the display object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have one body be a sensor and then in the collision listener have an event.phase == "began" stage where you set a flag (eg, isInside) to true.

Comment: Is there a way to know when a body is not overlapping the sensor anymore, so that I can set isInside to false?